# Xcode 8.3.3: How to Remember Username and Password and Add Touch-ID Authentication

Tags: ios, xcode, touch-id

My current project has a login page, but I find that the user must enter their username and password again when they log in. How do I make it easier for them, by implementing "remember username and password" functionality and adding Touch ID?

My code is as follows:

import UIKit

import Firebase

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

```
var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imageView = UIImageView(frame: view.bounds)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "background")
    imageView.center = view.center
    view.addSubview(imageView)
    self.view.sendSubview(toBack: imageView)

}

//Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!


//Login Action
@IBAction func loginAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if self.emailTextField.text == "" || self.passwordTextField.text == "" {

        //Alert to tell the user that there was an error because they didn't fill anything in the textfields because they didn't fill anything in

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please enter an email and password.", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {

        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: self.emailTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in

            if error == nil {

                //Print into the console if successfully logged in
                print("You have successfully logged in")

                //Go to the HomeViewController if the login is sucessful
                let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home")
                self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)

            } else {

                //Tells the user that there is an error and then gets firebase to tell them the error
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)

                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a couple of ways to save your user Credentials. Most common way is to save those in Keychain.

[KeyChain Swift](https://cocoapods.org/pods/KeychainSwift)

After that you can user your touchID authentication, by calling the default methods to implement this. Here is a nice tutorial how you should do it:

[Touch ID for Local Authentication](http://www.appcoda.com/touch-id-api-ios8/)